# Overriding AuthorizeCore in custom Authorize attribute but it allowing to direct access from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorize-attribute, form-authentication

i am trying to build custom AuthorizAttribute and overriding AuthorizeCore
it's working fine every where
but when i went to access restrict url which is not permitted without specific role, it allow me to go there. like when i hit URL  "http://localhost:8758/Classified/Attributes" it requires admin role but my code allowing to access it without admin role.
Am doing something wrong?
here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Classified.Web.Services;


namespace Classified.Web
{
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public IFormsAuthenticationService AuthenticationService { get; set; }

        public string RequiredRole;

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            AuthenticationService = new FormsAuthenticationService(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));

            var user = AuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser();

            if (user == null)
                return false;

            foreach (var i in user.Roles)
            {
                if (i.RoleName == RequiredRole)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: HUh............  i got an answer by my self :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution by my self...

There was a little mistake i just forgot to apply authorize before controller.
Something like that.

`[Authorize]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
    .
    .
    .`